What is the origin of the idiom"like stink"?
Cambridge labels the idiom British informal (I have doubts about that, I feel it is also used in the US) and says that:

If someone works like stink, they work extremely hard.

Free.dict gives a more nuanced definition:

Extremely fast, quickly, or rapidly.

Her motorcycle is flashy and it goes like stink, but it feels like you're gambling with your life every time you get on it.


I understand it is an adverbial intensifier, probably just like the phrase like mad. Phrase.finder has no entry for the origin of this idiom. Which makes me wonder whether perhaps its origin is unknown. Is it?

Green's Dictionary of Slang dates it to 1922 but no explanation of the origin. I wonder if it's connected with stink-bike, which Green's lists as slang for a motorbike from 1919, because it puts out lots of fumes and smoke. On the other hand "like shit" is an intensifier, c. 1940 slightly later than "like stink" but maybe connected, and compare "like crap".

@StuartF I doubt it is slang in its origin. It has been around since much earlier than that (have found instances from the 1800's).

See also Like hell, like mad, like stink : https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2024/05/like-stink.html

I suspect is a figurative use of the corruption of "stingo" (= a strong beer) OED -- b.
figurative. Vigour, energy, vim; to give (a person) hot stingo = to give it hot -- 1885
It's rare fun, by Jingo! I give 'em hot stingo. -- 1927 To keep in good trim and add stingo to your efforts in sport. Daily Telegraph 19 July 15.

I always supposed that it was from the speed at which bad odours can travel. Some cats will launch themselves away at warp speed after finishing with the litter box, as if to outrun the stink. I don't see any actual evidence of this, however.

@StuartF - my pal in 1970 said his new Triumph Bonneville went 'like shit off a shovel', and he emulated, with me on the back, someone who he had seen riding very fast along a residential street in East Dulwich (London, SE). he said 'That bloke pissed down Court Lane!'. So toilet metaphors for speed are a thing.  He said he managed 85 mph. Crazy times. I shudder to think what could have happened. It was 2 am.

The full OED has it as definition 3.b. 1929– like stink, furiously, intensely. Cf. like adv. B.1c. colloquial. Their first citation is 1929...

If you see a Minnie coming..you have to judge it and run like stink sometimes.

Elsewhere (under their definition for gangbusters) the OED explicitly says it's American1.
I suspect it might be a euphemism for...

{It goes} like shit {off a shovel}
and/or
{It goes} like fuck / hell / the blazes {the fires of hell}

It may be worth noting that the full OED doesn't explicitly say that like the dickens is euphemistic, but I'd say it's screamingly obvious that one at least gained / retained currency as a "quirky" alternative to like the devil. There needn't be much logic or semantics involved in such euphemisms.


1 OED: gangbusters - Canadian motor buffs mix English phrases like a bit of tweaking and needs breathing on with American ones like going Gangbusters and it goes like stink.

